# Not allowed to delete channel MyNotificationChannel with a foreground service - Android 10 and 11 java.lang.SecurityException

Tags: java, android, notifications, android-notifications, android-backup-service

I created notification channel when background service is running

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
        NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(channelId,
                    "Channel for  notification",
                    NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_NONE);
        mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
}
```

In `onDestroy` function I remove the notification by calling below method by passing the same channel name:

```
 notificationManager.deleteNotificationChannel(channelId);
```

When i try to delete that notification on some Devices running Android 10 and 11 got the SecurityException

Answer (score 0):

The First step is to neatly catch this exception using a try catch surround when you are trying to delete the channel. The idea is not to delete the channel when we have a foreground service running . So either the service should be stopped or we should not try to delete the channel

Comment: Please add further details to expand on your answer, such as working code or documentation citations.